# Query returns what i want, but wwhen i put into array the array_sum() doesn't add up my values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

Ok so my query is this:

```
select distinct `rate_id`, `p_id`, p_rate from shipping_rates inner join products_to_categories ptc inner join customers_basket cb on ptc.products_id = cb.products_id where cb.customers_id='1' and p_status = '1' and p_free = '0' group by p_id
```

which returns

```
rate_id   p_id  p_rate

1       1        10.00


2       22       11.00
```

which is what i want however when i add that to an array with

```
 $p_rate[] = $sInfo->p_rate;
 $rate = array_sum($p_rate);
```

this returns 10.00 not 21.00 like it should

by the way here is my code for the objectInfo class

```
    function objectInfo($object_array) {
      reset($object_array);
      while (list($key, $value) = each($object_array)) {
        $this->$key = tep_db_prepare_input($value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the code right below is

```
 $sRate = tep_db_fetch_array($status_query); 
  if ($sRate !=''){//error checking for empty query
      $sInfo = new objectInfo($sRate);
   }
```

trp_db_fetch_array() is just a function calling up mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Can you do a var_dump on the $p_rate array and post it here? I have a feeling there's a typecasting issue.

Comment: Definately need to see a print_r/var_dump of $p_rate. I would bet that it is a multi-dimensional array like `Array ( Array( 1), Array( 2),...etc)` with each row as a sub-array, not the one value like you are expecting.

Comment: so how do i get a singular array instead of this

Comment: i can't easily get a var_dump of the array as it is displayed in anouther page but maybe i can just write a simple php page to display the info

Comment: ok odd the var dump comes up null

Comment: ok i think i know what is going on i think

Comment: the query does return a result but the mysql_num_rows comes up null?

Comment: I have another if then statement that adds the rows together if there is more than one row else it defaults to $rate = $sInfo->p_rate; and that is what i'm seeing but why doesn't the $sRows work?

Comment: print_r returns 1 for $sRows

Comment: ok weird if i change the code to:

Comment: while( $sRate = mysql_fetch_array($status_query)){
  if ($sRate != ''){ //error checking for empty query
          $sInfo = new objectInfo($sRate);
          
       }
      
     }
     $sRows = mysql_num_rows($status_query);

Comment: it comes up with the other shipping rate of 11 but not 21.00

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the array_sum() INSIDE the fetch loop? e.g.

```
while($sInfo = fetch_from_db($result)) {
    $p_rate[] = $sInfo->p_rate;
    $rate = array_sum($p_rate);
}
```

? If so, then you'll have to move the summation to OUTSIDE the loop, so it only sums up after you've retrieve all of the data from the DB:

```
while($sInfo = fetch_from_db($result)) {
    $p_rate[] = $sInfo->p_rate;
}
$rate = array_sum($p_rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

$sInfo only contains one row. You need to fetch the whole result set first.

You seem to use a framework and not the native php functions. For this reason I cannot give the code used to do that.

Once you have the result set, you use :

```
foreach($sInfoTable as $sInfo){
    $p_rate[] = $sInfo->p_rate;
}
$rate = array_sum($p_rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out the answer by hunting and pecking here is the query

```
 $status_query = tep_db_query("select  `rate_id`, `p_id`, `p_rate`, cb.customers_id from " . TABLE_SHIPPING_RATES ." inner join ". TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " ptc inner join ". TABLE_CUSTOMERS_BASKET . " cb on cb.products_id = p_id where cb.customers_id='" . $customer_id ."' and p_status = '1' and p_free = '0' group by cb.customers_id,p_id");
```

and here is where i got all rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($status_query)){
 $p_rate[] = $row["p_rate"];
```

}

and here is where i summed up the rows:

```
$rate = array_sum($p_rate);
```

so now this doesn't need to count the rows or etc and is a lot cleaner